# Laravel 4 Class Not Found Exception - Class in Autoloader

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a "helper" class folder that I want to load into my application with `composer.json`. It looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "../shared_lib",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

After setting everything up I ran `composer dumpautoload` to load all the classes, and it seems to have worked. `my_project/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` clearly shows the classes that appear at any point in my `shared_lib` folder. When I try to access these classes in a controller a few work, and the rest are not found. I cannot figure out why. I tried playing with permissions, and regardless, get the same "Class Not Found" exception.

The funny thing is... this works elsewhere. I have another application, with the same settings, that finds the "missing" classes no problem. It should also be noted that the classes specified are in a subfolder in the `shared_lib` folder. I tried moving the classes to the root of `shared_lib` and nothing changed though.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'MyUniqueClass' not found","file":"\/var\/apps\/maps\/app\/controllers\/MyController.php","line":46}}
```

Comment: Could be a namespace issue. Can you please copy the exact error message you get?

Comment: Did you `dump autoload` after moving the classes to the root of `shared_lib`?

Comment: Yes I did. I've learned in working with laravel that if there ever is a weird problem, a `dump autoload` usually fixes it, so I do it all the time.